# Getting NoSuchElementException on webelement (Same webelement is getting found but sometimes i got the Exception)

Tags: java, exception, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I have created this test script to test a website. The problem is that sometime i am able to click edit button but sometime i am getting NoElementFoundException for the same button. I searched for the same type of problem on the forum and did the code changes as per recommended but non of them worked for me. In the attached picture i circled the button in red colour for which i am getting the exception.

[image]

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MonsterUpdateNewProfile {
    static WebDriver window=new FirefoxDriver();
    static WebElement wb;
    static String[] data;
    @Test(priority=2)
     static public boolean isAlertExist(){
         boolean alert=false;
         try{
            Alert alt= window.switchTo().alert();
            alert=true;
            System.out.println("Text from alert is "+alt.getText());
            alt.dismiss();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("No Alert");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return alert;
     }
     @Test
     static void dropdown() throws InterruptedException {
         wb=window.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ns_menu_item_wrap ns_lt active']/a"));
         Actions mouse=new Actions(window);
         mouse.moveToElement(wb).perform();
         Thread.sleep(4000);
         Select select=new Select(wb);
         select.selectByIndex(1);
         }//dropdown
     @Test
     public static void monster() throws InterruptedException {
        try{
        //connecting to web site by sending address url
        window.get("https://my.monsterindia.com/login.html?src=http://my.monsterindia.com/my_monster.html&rand=5257");
        window.manage().window().maximize();
        window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //finding username by using xpath
        wb=window.findElement(By.id("BodyContent:txtUsername"));
        //sending username
        wb.sendKeys("sshantanunandan@gmail.com");
        //finding and sending password
        window.findElement(By.id("BodyContent_txtPassword")).sendKeys("Ferrari2738");
        window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //finding and clicking on login button
        window.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
        //grtting the title of current page using getTitle() method
        System.out.println(window.getTitle());
        window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        window.findElement(By.name("cancel")).click();
        window.findElement(By.className("flyout_close")).click();
        //locating and clicking on update button which will open a new window
        window.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='http://media.monsterindia.com/monster_2012/btn_update2.gif']")).click();
        window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //capturing the title of oldwindow or the window which we go after loging 
        //using getWindowHandle() method
        String oldwindow=window.getWindowHandle();
        //by using for statement getting the title of new pop upwindow
        //here we can use if or while statement as well using getWindowHandles() method
        for(String newwindow : window.getWindowHandles()){
        //swithching to the new pop up using window.switchTo().window(passing newwindow as argument)    
        window.switchTo().window(newwindow);}
        //getting title of new window using getTitle() method
        System.out.println("NewWindow Title"+ window.getTitle());
        window.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='edit_resume_section3_open' and not(@disabled)]")).click();
        window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(window.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='title']")).getAttribute("value"));
        window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        window.findElement(By.id("update")).click();
        window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        window.close();
        //switching to oldwindow or main window
        //using switchTo().window(passing oldwindow url to it)
        //url which we captured in String oldwindow=window.getWindowHandle() method
        window.switchTo().window(oldwindow);
        //getting the output of old window
        System.out.println("OldWindow Title" + window.getTitle());
        //isAlertExist();
        //dropdown();
    }//try
        catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            window.findElement(By.className("flyout_close")).click();
            window.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='http://my.monsterindia.com/view_resume.html?resid=51706134&mode=edit']/img")).click();
            window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            window.findElement(By.id("edit_resume_section3_open")).click();
            window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println(window.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='title']")).getAttribute("value"));
            window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            window.findElement(By.id("edit_resume_section3_close_other")).click();
            window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            //isAlertExist();
            dropdown();
        }//catch
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Got Acception");
            window.close();
        }//catch
        finally{
            //dropdown();
            System.out.println("Finally Closing");
            window.close();
            window.quit();

        }//finally
  }//main
}//class

Exception got for this code-
   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='title']"}
 Command duration or timeout: 40.06 seconds
 For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'omega-d52b83806', ip: '10.0.0.5', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch:  'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: f4dce968-0425-4ba1-8a62-4ebdff91edc8
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true,  cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true,  browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=29.0.1}]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
at   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:404)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:363)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
at MonsterUpdateNewProfile.monster(MonsterUpdateNewProfile.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at  org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to  locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='title']"}
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'omega-d52b83806', ip: '10.0.0.5', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous591356915052066864webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8860)
at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous591356915052066864webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:396)
```

Comment: First, try running the XPath against the page to test it actually finds an element. You can do this using the Chrome console - $x("//input[@name='title']"). Is it possible that the page hasn't fully loaded, or that the name attribute varies?

Comment: @Romski I did it and the xpath is able to find the element. I put an implicitly wait also to give the page sufficient time to load.... Sir any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer as I couldn't work out how to place code in comments...

The error says it can't find the element, so either the XPath has an issue, or the element doesn't exist. You could try making the element your wait condition.

```
....
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 30)
window.findElement(By.id("...")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='title']")))
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='title']"))
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your XPath ".//*[@id='edit_resume_section3_open' and not(@disabled)]" correctness.

If it is correct then try to wait for this element and if it is available then only click on it.

You can use below code to wait for element:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)).until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
  public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
       return d.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='edit_resume_section3_open' and not(@disabled)]"));
    }
});
```